# Centos 7: veth interface starting at boot how do i find and disable it

Tags: centos7, linux-networking

Hi I have a centos 7 server which after removing the program (oracle vm maybe) has left an ophaned script which is starting a veth interface at boot how do I find which one it is in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts. I think thats the right location to be looking any any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: your question lags a lot of information... 
Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.

Comment: It would of been helpfull to state what is missing so i could provide it.

Comment: you said some program (which one) left some script in a path hows about to tell the content of the path? and tell us the name of the veth

Comment: I stated that I thought it was oracle above. The veth has a random number after it and has no connections to it or IP assigned.

Comment: show is an example output as text from `ip a`

Comment: I cant show you it as I have deleted the link and it will only start back when the server is restarted. The last one i deleted was called veth613aee5.

Comment: ive been digging through the logs and have found its something to do with docker 'docker0: port 1(veth613aee5) entered disabled state'

Comment: so it's solved?

Comment: Yes at least I know where to look now. thanks

Comment: sofar then please answer AND Accept your own, else we will have this question in the Database as unanswered until the end of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker is the problem starting an interface on boot which i will try and track down once its restarted again.